# Динамически изменять контрол в зависимости от входных данных

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Доброго времени суток!

В класс ViewModel имеется некоторая коллекция свойств объекта, полученная через рефлексию. В списке лежат свойства двух типов: строка и Enum. Как в xaml динамически породить тот или иной контрол (текстбокс или combobox), в зависимости от Item из списка свойств?

Класс-обёртка над свойством:

```
public class Property : Notifier
{
    private IOptionHolder SelectedSetting;
    private PropertyInfo PropertyInfo;

    public string PropertyName { set; get; }
    public Type PropertyType { set; get; }

    public object Value
    {
        get => PropertyInfo.GetValue(SelectedSetting);
        set
        {
            if (PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                PropertyInfo.SetValue(SelectedSetting,
                    Enum.Parse(PropertyType, value.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                PropertyInfo.SetValue(SelectedSetting,
                       Convert.ChangeType(value, PropertyInfo.PropertyType));
            }
        }
    }

    public Property(IOptionHolder selectedSetting, PropertyInfo pr)
    {
        SelectedSetting = selectedSetting;
        PropertyInfo = pr;

        PropertyName = pr.Name;
        PropertyType = pr.PropertyType;
    }
}
```

Во ViewModel заполняется коллекция этими свойствами

```
public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

В xaml пока ума не приложу, как реализовать динамическую подмену контролов.. В отдельности всё привязать руками получается и всё работает.
Ещё есть конвертер для отображения Enum в ComboBox.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Property property = (Property)value;

        if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            return Enum.GetValues(property.PropertyType);

        return property.Value;
    }
```

Comment: DataTrigger  - спасет отца русской демократии)

Comment: А можно компилируемый пример? Что такое `IOptionHolder`?

Comment: Проект слишком большой и IOptionHolder здесь не имеет никакого смысла, это просто объект, из которого я вытягиваю при помощи рефлексии значения нужных мне свойств

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать парадигму Template Selector,
вот пример: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_4.php

```
public class TypesTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate EnumDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ComboBoxDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
      // здесь вам нужно реализовать вашу проверку на тип, я просто скопировал часть кода из вопроса
        Property property = (Property)value;

        if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            return EnumDataTemplate;
        }
        .. остальные проверки   
      return null;

    }
```

В ресурсах контрола, который вы используете, надо создать DataTemplate

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumDataTemplate">
    ... ваш шаблон
    </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDataTemplate">
    ... ваш шаблон
    </DataTemplate>
```

И использовать вот так

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
             <local:TypesTemplateSelector 
                      EnumDataTemplate="{StaticResource EnumDataTemplate}"
                      ComboBoxDataTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}"/>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот пример чуть понятнее и выглядит более логично

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего, наверное, определить ваши `DataTemplate`'ы. Пример:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='String: {0}'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='Enum: {0}'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Коллекция:

```
DataContext = new object[]
{
    "I'm string",
    HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    "I'm another string",
    AttributeTargets.Class 
};
```

Результат:

[image: всё просто]

Answer (score 1):

Спецом под вашу задачу пилить не буду, кину как есть в моем проекте.
Это будет ItemTemplate Для некого listView:

```
<ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger  Value="True" Binding="{Binding AccState, Converter={StaticResource AccountStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:AccountStateEnum.Load}}">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource LoadTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger  Value="True" Binding="{Binding AccState, Converter={StaticResource AccountStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:AccountStateEnum.Fail}}">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource AutFailTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

И сам конвертер для этого дела:

```
public class AccountStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null || value == null) return false;
        try
        {
            var t = (int)parameter == (int)value;
            return t;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше использовать TemplateSelector

Comment: Ну можно и так, не помню уже почему мне то ли не понравилось, то ли в моей задаче не подошло. Но оба способа рабочие